# Fix Django "Unresolved attribute reference" for prefetched field

Tags: python, django, django-orm, type-hinting, prefetch

Let's say I have the following Django models:

```
class Toolbox(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tools = models.ManyToManyField("Tool")

class Tool(models.Model):
    class Size(models.TextChoices):
        SMALL = "S"
        MEDIUM = "M"
        LARGE = "L"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Size.choices)
```

I have a function to get all small tools for each toolbox. The `@queries_disabled()` comes from django-zen-queries to ensure the small tools have been prefetched and avoid N+1 performance problems.

```
@queries_disabled()
def get_toolbox_to_small_tools_mappings(toolboxes: list[Toolbox]) -> dict:
    return {toolbox: toolbox.small_tools for toolbox in toolboxes}
```

The problem is my editor (PyCharm) is highlighting a warning:

> Unresolved attribute reference 'small_tools' for class 'Toolbox'

I can fix this my changing the argument's type hint:

```
def get_toolbox_to_small_tools_mappings(toolboxes: list[Toolbox] | QuerySet): ...
```

This feels a little hacky to me. Is there a better way to fix this?

Moreover, I would like to provide a helpful error message to the function caller if they forget to prefetch this data. Right now the error message is:

> AttributeError: 'Toolbox' object has no attribute 'small_tools'

How can I provide a more explicit error message that says something like:

> 'Toolbox' object has no attribute 'small_tools'. You must prefetch this field.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does this feel hacky? Toolboxes *would* be a queryset here right?

Comment: I don't like the `Union` here. I would much rather do something like `QuerySet[Toolbox]`. But that doesn't seem possible based on my research.

Comment: Yeah, not without django-stubs. WRT the error message, couldn’t you catch the AttributeError and raise your own exception?

Comment: Looks like [WithAnnotations](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs#how-do-i-annotate-cases-where-i-called-querysetannotate) from django-stubs is what I need here